# How to call $.dspBody() function in Mura without actually displaying the content?

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I need to display the search results after a user searches. The results weren't showing so I went looking and according to this [Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mura-cms-developers/DamYdtBExCY/Pd6mPEu085gJ),
I needed to call the `.dspBody()` function.

I  added that function to my template like so,

`#$.dspBody(body='', title='',summary='', crumbList=false, showMetaImage=false)#`

and then the search results started showing up right where I called that function.

However, the problem is that the content of the page is displayed further down the template using,

```
#$.content('title')#

#$.content('body')#
```

and so on. Therefore calling `.dspBody()` above where I want the search results to be results in the content being duplicated onto the page.

I reviewed the [documentation for the function](https://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/creating-layout-templates/template-variables-helper-methods/dspbody/) and didn't see an option for calling the functions without displaying the content.

**Is there a way of calling `.dspBody()` so that no content appears?**

Comment: Have you tried `<cfsavecontent>` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler No, would I use that to substitute for the first or the second code blocks?

Comment: Try putting `<cfsavecontent variable="bodyContent">#$.dspBody(body='', title='',summary='', crumbList=false, showMetaImage=false)#</cfsavecontent>` and use `#bodyContent#` instead of `#$.content('body')#`

Comment: I was thinking what @RRK did

Comment: @RRK I did that, but then I had extra content showing up where I called the `#bodyContent#` it was showing the page associated image in addition to the text